# Is it possible to use the value of another field when validating a multidimensional array in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a multidimensional array containing dates and I want to validate that the dates are more than 18 years apart.

I am using Laravel Validator but I am getting error:

> "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (DateofBirth) at position 0 (D): The timezone could not be found in the database".

The code I am using is as below:

```
$validator = Validator::make($members, [
    '*.DateofBirth'  => "required|date|before:" . now('Africa/Nairobi')->addYears(-18),
    '*.DateEmployed' => 'date|before_or_equal:today|after:'.Carbon::parse(*.DateofBirth)->addYears(18),
]);
```

How can I pass "*.DateofBirth" in the validation of DateEmployed?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value of a different field for the `before` and `after` rules, however, you can't manipulate that value.

One way to get around this would be to use a [custom validation closure](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#using-closures):

```php
'*.DateEmployed' => [
    'date',
    'before_or_equal:today',
    function ($attr, $value, $fail) use ($members) {

        $date = Carbon::parse($value);
        $dob = Carbon::parse(data_get($members, str_replace('DateEmployed', 'DateofBirth', $attr)));

        if ($dob->addYears(18)->isAfter($date)) {
            $fail('The :attribute must be at least 18 years after DateofBirth');
        }
    },
],
```